# String.Equals GID returning false?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, localization

I have the following C# code in my ASP.NET MVC application. I try to compare 2 `string` using the `Equals` method, with `culture = "vi"`. My code below:

```
string culture = "vi";

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 
  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

var CCC = string.Equals("CategId", "CATEGID", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
var xx = string.Equals("TestGID", "TestGID", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
var zz = string.Equals("id", "ID", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Results:

> CCC = **false**;
>
> xx = true;
>
> zz = true;

I don't know why `CCC` is `false`. Is there anything wrong? If I set `culture = id, ko, en`, etc... then `CCC = true`. Who can help me?

Comment: This throws an exception: `Culture 'vi' is a neutral culture. It cannot be used in formatting and parsing and therefore cannot be set as the thread's current culture.` You need to use `vi-VN` (although that will still return `false`)

Comment: For non-GUI applications, instead use `StringComparer Comparer = StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("vi-VN"), true);
                            Comparer.Equals("CategId", "CATEGID");`  This is because current culture is slow.

Comment: As the strings you're comparing are "clearly" (for some value of "clear") in English-or-English-like, you should, as Kevin suggests, use the `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`. We had a similar problem with "settings names" when someone using Turkish triggered the [Dotted and dotless I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I) problem, where `SID` no longer equals `sid` even when ignoring case.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is `gI` which *is not* equal to `GI` in case of *Vietnamese language*. `gi` (`GI`) is syllable-initial, kind of *one letter* while `gI` are *two* separate letters. Other pairs are

```
cH != CH
kH != KH
nG != NG
nH != NH
pH != PH
qU != QU
tH != TH
tR != TR
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnamese_language

Answer (score 7):

You can try

```
string culture = "vi";

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 
  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

var CCC = string.Equals("CategId", "CATEGID", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
var CCC1 = string.Equals("CategId", "CATEGID", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

In this `CCC` will return `true` but `CCC1` will return `false` because of *Culture*. as per your Culture `GID` and `gId` is different.